# How to run job on jenkins that need authentication using Rest API?

Tags: javascript, basic-authentication

I want to create a Javascript Application that talks to a jenkins server hosted (say http://myjenkinsserver.com/jenkins. This jenkins server needs a user to be authenticated to run any job. The authentication needed is BASIC Http. I have my username: johnsmith and password: jenkinsjob. I also have the API token.

My doubt is how do i authenticate and store any token somewhere to use it to start/stop builds etc.

Thanks in advance.

P.S: Reference -

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/) and its [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function that defined a `username` and `password` options.

Then, you can store your token in a [`localStorage`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Comment: Its not the functional difficulty I am facing. I do not know how do i do it? What should be the URL to which i need to do a POST request. What response do i get? and all.

Comment: All is defined in your link: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients

Comment: Its defined for various platforms. Like java, groovy etc. I want to know how do you do it in javascript. More over if you could tell how can one do it in a REST Client from Browser, That would be a lot helpful. When I tried doing the things mentioned at "https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients" I am always getting 403 Forbidden.

Comment: The doc say "Note that Jenkins does not do any authorization negotiation. Ie. it immediately returns a 403 (Forbidden) response instead of a 401 (Unauthorized) response, so make sure to send the authentication information from the first request (aka "preemptive authentication".)". JQuery (and html ajax stack) doesn't do preemptive authentication.

Comment: Okay. Could suggest any other option if I have one? The main purpose is to create a phonegap application that does job building. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had a smiliar problem. Try looking at [This HTTP Pluggin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTTP+Request+Plugin).

```
function LastSuccessfulBuild(callback, iParams) {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: (iParams.url+"/job/"+iParams.job+"/lastSuccessfulBuild"),
        username: myUsername,
        password: myPassword,
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        getSuccess(callback, response)
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        getFailed(response);
    });
}
```

Works for me